# calling an await within a then

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have the following code...

```
  run(cert).then( serverPop => {
    const popInt = parseInt(serverPop);
    console.log("The new pop resport is: " + serverPop);
    if (oldPop < popInt) {
      let addDB = "https://www.website.com/u.php?o=" + oldPop + "&c=" + cert + "&n=" + popInt;
      const popIntoDoResponse = await axios.get(addDB); //error here
      res.json({
        ack: "success",
        message: "POP IS UPDATED",
        pop: popInt,
        serverResponse: popIntoDoResponse.data
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        ack: "success",
        message: "POP IS THE SAME",
        pop: popInt
      });
    }
```

I get the following within the logs which points to the `await`

> await is only valid in async function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `async` inside the then method.

```
run(cert).then(async (serverPop) => { // add `async`
    const popInt = parseInt(serverPop);
    console.log("The new pop resport is: " + serverPop);
    if (oldPop < popInt) {
      let addDB = "https://www.website.com/u.php?o=" + oldPop + "&c=" + cert + "&n=" + popInt;
      const popIntoDoResponse = await axios.get(addDB); //error here
      res.json({
        ack: "success",
        message: "POP IS UPDATED",
        pop: popInt,
        serverResponse: popIntoDoResponse.data
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        ack: "success",
        message: "POP IS THE SAME",
        pop: popInt
      });
    }
```

Comment: ahhh, thank you! works like a charm. ill accept when im able!